# How to get Icons at the top of my Mac Screen

Tags: macos, menu, dropbox

On the very top of my Mac, there is a bar which has my battery percentage, the date and time, the volume, etc. There is also a dropbox folder. How can I create something that gets thrown up there? I'd like to put a few shortcuts in that menu bar. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you asking for a code example or an OS tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bar is the equivalent to the system notification bar on Windows. You want to place your shortcuts on the dock (normally located at the bottom of your screen). You do this by drag and dropping.

> While OS X provides no centralized tool to enable or configure menu extras, some of them can be rearranged and dragged off the menubar while depressing the ⌘ key. Also, all Apple-supplied menu extras can be found in the folder /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_extra)

However, if you are determined to put your shortcuts on the bar, here is [how to create menu extras](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000078.php)

Alternatively, there are some free apps already created for this purpose. [HimmelBar](http://softbend.free.fr/himmelbar/) - Free, [XMenu](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/freeware/) - Free, and [MoofMenu](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/MoofMenu/) - $5

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `NSStatusBarItem` class (see also the `NSStatusBar` class which represents the menu bar itself.)

Note that icons/menus created with this API do not "mix and match" with the OS-provided ones, but rather are aligned to the left of them and cannot be dragged by the user. Still, it's good enough for most uses.